# Search exact string in list

Tags: python, regex, string, match

I am doing an exercise where I need to search the exact function name from the `fun` list and get the corresponding information from another list `detail`.

Here is the dynamic list `detail`:

```
csvCpReportContents =[
['[PLT] rand (DEBUG INFO NOT FOUND)', '11', '15'],
['rand', '10', '11', '12'],
['__random_r', '23', '45'],
['__random', '10', '11', '12'],
[],
['multiply_matrices()','23','45'] ]
```

Here is `fun` list contains function name to be searched:

```
fun = ['multiply_matrices()','__random_r','__random']
```

Expected Output for function `fun[2]`

```
 ['__random', '10', '11', '12']
```

Expected Output for function `fun[1]`

```
['__random_r', '23', '45'],
```

Here what I have tried for `fun[2]`:

```
for i in range(0, len(csvCpReportContents)):
    row = csvCpReportContents[i]
    if len(row)!=0:
        search1 = re.search("\\b" + str(fun[2]).strip() + "\\b", str(row))
        if search1:
            print(csvCpReportContents[i])
```

Please suggest to me how to search for the exact word and fetch only that information.

Comment: Your expected outcome is the the same as your current "wrong input"?

Comment: Do you only want to search in the first list element in each row in `csvCpReportContents`?

Comment: See https://ideone.com/SEWITf

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, It is not coming for `fun[1]`

Comment: It is not quite relevant. You have not outlined the requirements in the question. You just can't use `str(row)` as input for `re.search` as `row` is a list. That is the point. See the answers below showing the same approach with a tweak to search at the start of each item. They deduced it from the sample strings you posted, but the regex you used implies you need a match anywhere inside the string. Please update the question with what you really need.

Comment: @MrFuppes, I want only to search from the `fun list` as the details list is large  and contains another unnecessary first list element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for each fun function you can just iterate through the csv list checking if the first element starts with it

```
csvCpReportContents = [
    ['[PLT] rand (DEBUG INFO NOT FOUND)', '11', '15'],
    ['rand', '10', '11', '12'],
    [],
    ['multiply_matrices()', '23', '45']]

fun=['multiply_matrices()','[PLT] rand','rand']

for f in fun:
    for c in csvCpReportContents:
        if len(c) and c[0].startswith(f):
            print(f'fun function {f} is in csv row {c}')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
fun function multiply_matrices() is in csv row ['multiply_matrices()', '23', '45']
fun function [PLT] rand is in csv row ['[PLT] rand (DEBUG INFO NOT FOUND)', '11', '15']
fun function rand is in csv row ['rand', '10', '11', '12']
```

Updated code since you changed the test cases and requirement in the question. My first answer was based on your test cases that you wanted to match lines that started with item from fun. Now you seem to have changed that requirement to match an exact match and if not exact match match a starts with match. Below code updated to handle that scenario. However i would say next time be clear in your question and dont change the criteria after several people have answered

```
csvCpReportContents =[
['[PLT] rand (DEBUG INFO NOT FOUND)', '11', '15'],
['rand', '10', '11', '12'],
['__random_r', '23', '45'],
['__random', '10', '11', '12'],
[],
['multiply_matrices()','23','45'] ]

fun = ['multiply_matrices()','__random_r','__random','asd']

for f in fun:
    result = []
    for c in csvCpReportContents:
        if len(c):
            if f == c[0]:
                result = c
            elif not result and c[0].startswith(f):
                result = c

    if result:
        print(f'fun function {f} is in csv row {result}')
    else:
        print(f'fun function {f} is not vound in csv')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
fun function multiply_matrices() is in csv row ['multiply_matrices()', '23', '45']
fun function __random_r is in csv row ['__random_r', '23', '45']
fun function __random is in csv row ['__random', '10', '11', '12']
fun function asd is not vound in csv
```

Comment: Your code is not working for the updated test case and the fun list. Could you please go through it. Thanks!!

Comment: your first test cases were you wanted to match lines which started with. You need to decide what your match criteria is. like why should `[PLT] rand` match `['[PLT] rand (DEBUG INFO NOT FOUND)', '11', '15']` but `__random` shouldnt match `['__random_r', '23', '45']`

Comment: @ I have recently come across this new constraint.

Comment: ok so can you redefine the search requirement. Under what criteria should the item in FUN be found in CSV?

Comment: I have updated my answer based on an assumption about what your trying to do

Answer (score 1):

above input is nested list, so you have to consider 2D Indexing such as 
l = [[1,2,3,4],[2,5,7,9]]
for finding 3 number element
you have to use the index of l[0][2]

Answer (score 1):

With custom `search_by_func_name` function:

```
csvCpReportContents = [
    ['[PLT] rand (DEBUG INFO NOT FOUND)', '11', '15'],
    ['rand', '10', '11', '12'],
    [],
    ['multiply_matrices()', '23', '45']]

fun = ['multiply_matrices()', '[PLT] rand', 'rand']


def search_by_func_name(name, content_list):
    for lst in content_list:
        if any(i.startswith(name) for i in lst):
            return lst


print(search_by_func_name(fun[1], csvCpReportContents))  # ['[PLT] rand (DEBUG INFO NOT FOUND)', '11', '15']
print(search_by_func_name(fun[2], csvCpReportContents))  # ['rand', '10', '11', '12']
```

Comment: Your code is not working for the updated test case and the fun list. Could you please go through it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use call_fun function as I did in the below code.

```
def call_fun(fun_name):
    for ind,i in enumerate(csvCpReportContents):
        if i:
            if i[0].startswith(fun_name):
                return csvCpReportContents[ind]
```

# call_fun(fun[2])

# ['rand', '10', '11', '12']

Comment: Your code is not working for the updated test case and the fun list. Could you please go through it. Thanks!!

Comment: Now i have used the startswith function. I hope with will work for you.